# WSO2 Identity Server - Federated Mode with SAML, Domain Name?

Tags: wso2, identity, saml, federation, wso2-identity-server

Could you please explain why the WSO2 Travelocity test application requests a "Domain Name" input field in the sign-in screen, when the WSO2 is configured to use, beside basic auth, also a federated authentication mode (WS Release 5.1 - Advanced Configuration). What is the reason to request  the domain name part, as for external authentication, for example by use of SAML protocol, I expect to see a redirect onto the external IdP login screen. Apparently the Login redirect is rejected due to this missing input field at the Domain Name.  Is there a sample configuration and use case available for setup of outgoing IdP federation?

**Further Details from Testings**

I've updated the IdP configuration following the WSo2 setting which describes the federation effort with help of Shibboleth products (see below). After this change now I see a login screen from the external IdP ("zee") as well as an interchange of messages between the browser and the external IdP. I also see a SAML POST message in the SSO protocol tracer plugin of the Browser, displaying a long list of claim assertion data, which signals that Login was successfully processed, returning the profile data of my account.

At the Travelocity service provider (SP), now I see the following error message at the screen:

"The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."

I've validated the SAML feedback data and its XML format consistency using an online XML validator, which passed successfully for SAML response XSD format. Such type of XML parser errors are often caused by use of special characters, but its not the case at the current assertions and tests.
The issue happens inside the Travelocity which has difficulties to read the SAML assertion data.

Suggestions from the community how to parse the SAML feedback data using the Travelocity tool, are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On for configuring Basic scenario with travelocity app

To configure federated authenticators: 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Federated+Authentication

For Advanced Configuration with Multiple Authenticators
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider

Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/How+To%3A+Configure+Shibboleth+IdP+as+a+Trusted+Identity+Provider as an example use case.

It seems that you have custom authentication since you have domain name filed at the login prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the links with configuration guide. I've succeed to setup a federated SSO login between the Travelocity Service Provider and two IdP's using outgoing federation without the advanced option, following the guidelines referenced above.